# Length of data to decrypt is Invalid

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

I've been researching an issue I'm having while attempting to decrypt using the Rijndael C# libraries. I've tried several solutions that have been posted on here but none seem to work or apply.

The issue: I'm attempting to decrypt a HTTP Request that is sent from a piece of hardware. However, I'm not getting the HTTP request converted into the correct number of bytes that match my decryption methods( I Think this is the issue?).

Here is my code:

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
System.Text.Encoding req = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;

if (curContext != null)
{
    string decrypted = "";
    int totalBytes = curContext.Request.TotalBytes;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(curContext.Request.InputStream);
    string request = sr.ReadToEnd();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request)) 
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            byte[] key = enc.GetBytes(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["32B"].ToString());
            myRijndael.KeySize = 256;
            myRijndael.Key = key;

            decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes(req.GetBytes(request), myRijndael.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

And Decrypt method:

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key)
{
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor();

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                    // and place them in a string.
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the srDecrypt.ReadToEnd() I get the error message stated in title.

I'm rather new to this so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks~!

Comment: Why are you using two different `RijndaelManaged` objects?  The one in your upper code appears to do nothing.

Comment: There is other code that is used to encrypt a response and send back. That object is used there, but that part is working correctly and not necessary to add here.

Comment: Seeing hows its encrypted will help make sure your decryption matches.

Comment: What I am trying to decrypt is encrypted on a piece of hardware, and is not done by my code. I do however, have to encrypt and send an HTTP reponse back. Not the same process.

Comment: Is the ASCII encoding used when you encrypt it when seding the HTTP response back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Stream to string to bytes" conversion sequence feels very wrong. Make sure you really need to do it instead of simply reading bytes from response.

Comment: You are passing `byte[]` to your DecryptStringFromBytes methods. It is unclear if you need `stream->string->byte[]` conversion. Note that it could be perfectly fine - just look wrong thing to do.

Comment: Are you saying just use enc.GetBytes(curContext.Request.Inputstream.ToString())? That wouldn't work..

Comment: I would expect reading bytes directly from stream, but I have no idea what you need to do in **your** case.  As I've said your code for reading the data could be perfectly fine as is.

Comment: @Encryption - Have you tried converting the steam to a byte[] and convert the byte[] to a string?  Seems strange that a StreamReader.ReadToEnd() would give you the error you claim it does.

Comment: @ramhound  The issue was the use of the StreamReader setting the InputStream to string. Converting directly to byte gave me the correct number of bytes which is what I needed and stopped the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead at the bottom of your Decrypt method:

```
int plainByteCount = int.MinValue;

// Create the streams used for decryption.
using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
{
  using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
  {
    plainBytes = new byte[cipherText.Length];
    plainByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
  }
}

string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainByteCount);

return plainText;
```

Comment: Where are y ou getting plainTextBytes from?

Comment: Still get same error message. The number of bytes is 122...I thought it should be 128 though?

Comment: Sorry I might have time later today to help you.

Comment: @Encryption - Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found your problem. According to the constructor for [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at.aspx), the default encoding is `UTF8Encoding`.  Trying using the other constructor overload and pass in the ASCII encoding:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
   curContext.Request.InputStream, Encoding.ASCII);
string request = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: As UTF-8 is a full superset of ASCII, I really don't see what this would accomplish.